# One word for "a person who takes happiness as his/her goal of life"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm unable to remember a single-word substitute for "a person who takes happiness as his/her goal of life"

Comment: What kind of happiness? Pleasure? Charity? Sexual fulfillment? Success? Being the best person you could be? All? Other? There are different words for the different things that make people happy. A *hedonist* lives for *pleasure* but not necessarily happiness.

Comment: You might be looking for _hedonist_, although he sets _pleasure_ as his goal - which presumably leads to happiness.

Comment: @medica: pleasure

Comment: @oerkelens: hedonist is correct :) :)

Comment: Hedonists seek pleasure, not happiness. Ultimately, while experiencing pleasure might make one happy during the experience, a hedonistic lifestyle and its pursuit of fleeting shallow pleasure is likely to lead to unhappiness. But then perhaps I'm just a pessimist.

Comment: They're 'Normal'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Eudaemonism](http://universalium.academic.ru/15450/eudaemonism)** the ethical doctrine that personal happiness is the chief good and the proper aim of action

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a single word for this concept, although **epicure** is one devoted to sensual pleasure (in its older sense). Further along that wavelength is the word **libertine**.

Answer (score 0):

voluptuary: a life devoted to the pursuit of enjoyment of luxury and pleasure;

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This may have been derived from the Free Dictionary. If it is, please [attribute the source](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Plagiarism is liable to deletion.