# What's a word for describing people who only search for happiness and joy in their lives

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of this word and it's driving me crazy. I've used it before and I believe it ends with ist/ism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One word for "a person who takes happiness as his/her goal of life"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174922/one-word-for-a-person-who-takes-happiness-as-his-her-goal-of-life)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for *hedonist* and *hedonism*.  Wiktionary defines *hedonism* as:

> The belief that pleasure or happiness is the highest good in life. Some hedonists, such as the Epicureans, have insisted that pleasure of the entire mind, not just pleasure of the senses, is the highest good.

Comment: Yes that's the word! Thank you!

Comment: I think hedonists have a (perhaps unfair) characterization of favoring personal happiness at the expense of others.